# Orbits of some special actions on solution set of a arithmetic equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, geometric-group-theory, group-actions

Let $g_1(x,y,z)=(y,x,-z), g_2(x,y,z)=(y,x+y+2z,-y-z)$,
$V= \{(x,y,z)\in Z^3|xy-z^2+1=0 \}$.
Is it possible to find all orbits of the action of group $\langle g_1 \rangle * \langle g_2 \rangle$ on $V$?  How can I find all of them?

Comment: I have already known that the graph of the action on any point in the set is a tree. I want to know how can the set be covered by these disjunct trees.

Comment: (Correcting erased false comment, sorry.) The group generated by these two matrices acts (absolutely) irreducibly. Indeed otherwise there would be a nontrivial invariant subspace, and taking the orthogonal there is a common eigenline and it's easy to see it's not the case. So we get an absolutely irreducible subgroup of $SO(q)$, where $q(x,y,z)=xy-z^2$. It's easy to deduce that it's Zariski-dense in $SO(q)$. This implies that reduction mod $p$ is surjective for large $p$, so mod large $p$ there's a single orbit. Hence maybe there are finitely many orbits.

Comment: @YCor Sorry, I don't understand why you consider the $SO(q)$ because $g_2$ is not in $SO(q)$, right?

Comment: Yes $g_2$ is in $SO(q)$. It has determinant 1, and $q(g_2(x,y,z))=y(x+y+2z)-(-y-z)^2=q(x,y,z)$. (If $g_2$ were not in in $O(q)$ it would probably not preserve $V$.)

Comment: @YCor I see. But can you give me more details why the subgroup is Zariski dense in this general orthogonal group because I'm not familiar with algebraic group, thx.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this note of Don Zagier?

- [A One-Sentence Proof that every $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ is a sum of two squares](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2323918/fulltext.pdf)?

His map might be related:

$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto \left\{ 
\begin{array}{cl} (x+2z, z, y - x - z ) & \text{if }x< y - z \\
(2y-x, y, x - y + z) & \text{if }y-z < x < 2y \\
(x-2y, x-y+z,y)& \text{if }x > 2y
 \end{array}
 \right. $$
He claims (but does not really prove) it is involution on  $X = \{ x^2 + 4yz = p\}$ with exactly one fixed point - if $p$ is prime - so that involution $(x,y,z) \mapsto (y,x,z)$ is also a fixed point.

---

It is simplification of this argument by [Roger Heath-Brown](http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/677/1/invariant.pdf).

Comment: One of the links in the post seems to be dead - to prevent the link rot, here are Wayback Machine links for the [first one](http://web.archive.org/web/20190815122545/http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2323918/fulltext.pdf) and the [second one](http://web.archive.org/web/20181101074814/http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/677/1/invariant.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but some comments:

1. The quadratic form $q$ (as in YCor's comment) has signature $(-, -, +)$ so the group is a fuchsian group.
2. A fuchsian group is Zariski-dense if and only if it is non-elementary. It is pretty clear that this group is non-elementary (because $g_1$ acts non-trivially on the limit points on $g_2.$)
3. One does not even need the fact above, but using the results of T. Weigel, one can check surjectivity (onto $SO(3, p))$ for a single $p\geq 3$.
4. So, as Yves says, there is one orbit mod large $p$, but
5. This does not give us much, since the most studied of such objects - the Apollonian group (see the original papers of Grahah, Lagarias, Mallows, Wilks, but also the amazing later papers of Sarnak, Fuchs, Bourgain, Gamburd...) is likewise Zariski dense, but, nevertheless, has infinitely many orbits.

Finally, it should be remarked that your $V$ is the de Sitter sphere (sphere of radius $1$ for your quadratic form). That makes life slightly more annoying than if it were the hyperbolic plane.